# how to make it so event listener within for loop pushes one item per click to array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an array of image class names that the user has clicked. I'm doing this using a 'for' loop and an event listener. When one of the images is clicked, its class name is added to an array and at the end of the program the items in the array are displayed.

The problem is that when I check my console log there are multiple events being recorded by the log each time, rather than the single new selection.

Why is this happening and how do I get around it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>JavaScript Discovery Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="main-container" class="set-1 set-wrapper">
            <div id="col-1" class="col-1 col">

            </div>
            <div id="col-2" class="col-2 col">
              </div>
            <div id="col-3" class="col-3 col">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
var wrapperNode = document.querySelector("#main-container");
function imageSwapper(oldClass, newClass) {
    console.log("in imageSwapper");
    wrapperNode.classList.remove(oldClass);
    wrapperNode.classList.add(newClass);
}
var resultsArray = [];
console.log(wrapperNode);
wrapperNode.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("wrapperNode Clicked");

    window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        console.log("window listener");
        console.log(event);
        console.log(event.toElement.className);
        resultsArray.push(event.toElement.className);
        console.log(resultsArray);
    });

    if (wrapperNode.classList.contains("set-1")) {
        console.log("set-1 if");

        imageSwapper("set-1", "set-2");
    } else if (wrapperNode.classList.contains("set-2")) {
        console.log("set-2 if");
        imageSwapper("set-2", "set-3");
    } else if (wrapperNode.classList.contains("set-3")) {
        console.log("set-3 if");
        imageSwapper("set-3", "set-4");
```

```css
.set-1 .col-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.set-1 .col-2 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.set-1 .col-3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.set-2 .col-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/stone.jpg");
}
.set-2 .col-2 {
  background-image: url("../img/bread.jpg");
}
.set-2 .col-3 {
  background-image: url("../img/pillow.jpg");
}

.set-3 .col-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/polkaDots.jpg");
}
.set-3 .col-2 {
  background-image: url("../img/wavePattern.jpg");
}
.set-3 .col-3 {
  background-image: url("../img/squares.jpg");
}

.set-4 .col-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/pencilTip.jpg");
}
.set-4 .col-2 {
  background-image: url("../img/blankPage2.jpg");
}
.set-4 .col-3 {
  background-image: url("../img/eraser.jpg");
}
```

This should log each col that a user selects and store it in an array, but it keeps exponentially increasing with each click. The console log below has recorded a total of three clicks. I clicked the first col on my first click, the second col on my second and the third col on my third click.

```
hello
script.js:21 <div id=​"main-container" class=​"set-1 set-wrapper">​…​</div>​
script.js:23 wrapperNode Clicked
script.js:34 set-1 if
script.js:16 in imageSwapper
script.js:26 window listener
script.js:27 MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 429, screenY: 486, clientX: 409, clientY: 348, …}
script.js:28 col-1 col
script.js:30 ["col-1 col"]
script.js:23 wrapperNode Clicked
script.js:38 set-2 if
script.js:16 in imageSwapper
script.js:26 window listener
script.js:27 MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 879, screenY: 501, clientX: 859, clientY: 363, …}
script.js:28 col-2 col
script.js:30 (2) ["col-1 col", "col-2 col"]
script.js:26 window listener
script.js:27 MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 879, screenY: 501, clientX: 859, clientY: 363, …}
script.js:28 col-2 col
script.js:30 (3) ["col-1 col", "col-2 col", "col-2 col"]
script.js:23 wrapperNode Clicked
script.js:41 set-3 if
script.js:16 in imageSwapper
script.js:26 window listener
script.js:27 MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1437, screenY: 477, clientX: 1417, clientY: 339, …}
script.js:28 col-3 col
script.js:30 (4) ["col-1 col", "col-2 col", "col-2 col", "col-3 col"]
script.js:26 window listener
script.js:27 MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1437, screenY: 477, clientX: 1417, clientY: 339, …}
script.js:28 col-3 col
script.js:30 (5) ["col-1 col", "col-2 col", "col-2 col", "col-3 col", "col-3 col"]
script.js:26 window listener
script.js:27 MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1437, screenY: 477, clientX: 1417, clientY: 339, …}
script.js:28 col-3 col
script.js:30 (6) ["col-1 col", "col-2 col", "col-2 col", "col-3 col", "col-3 col", "col-3 col"]
```

Above, it appears my program is recording everything exponentially. The readout should be:

script.js:30 (2) ["col-1 col", "col-2 col", "col-3 col"]

instead i'm getting:

script.js:30 (6) ["col-1 col", "col-2 col", "col-2 col", "col-3 col", "col-3 col", "col-3 col"]

Answer (score 1):

In the click event of your wrapperNode you are adding an event listener to the window. Every time someone clicks the wrapperNode a new event listener is added but never removed. This would explain the exponentially increasing output. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I think either you should remove the previous event listener before adding the new, or you should just apply the inner event listener once, and not adding it every time wrapperNode is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery it would look like this

When you create each image, just add the same class to each one. That way you only need one event. eg. 'img'. You can even remove the 'img' string before pushing it to the array.

```
var list = [];

$('.img').click(function(e){
    list.push( this.className.replace('img','') );
    console.log(list.toString());
});
```